# Why doesn't my laptop fan ever spin down?

Tags: linux, laptop, fan

My laptop fan is always active, even if CPU usage is really low (less than 5%). I have a Vaio laptop with Linux and Windows, but this problem only happens with Linux.

Comment: this kind of thing depends on your hardware. which model do you have *exactly*?

Comment: well I think it doesn't depend on my hardware, because it only happens with Linux! so at least it can be a driver problem

Comment: @Simone: it depends on your hardware because it doesn't happen in every machine. That doesn't mean it's a problem *of* your hardware.

Comment: What about temperature? Was it too "high"?

Comment: I had one Vaio laptop that always had this problem with Linux. I had a second Vaio laptop that always had this problem with FreeBSD. No more Vaio laptops.

Answer (score 4):

## Sony Vaio Laptops

I have found an invaluable resource of information from [this Google code page](https://code.google.com/p/vaio-f11-linux/).

#### ACPI

I suggest you start there and work your way around the internet using keywords such as **ACPI**.  ACPI is what allows your OS to control things such as fans, power-state (hibernation and resume), screen brightness among other things.

#### lm-sensors

Try installing lm-sensors via your package manager and run it via **sensors -f**.  Your computer may simply not be aware of it's temperature, and is making sure it stays nice and cool.

#### BIOS Updates

Many Vaio models have somewhat recent BIOS updates what are supposed to fix such issues.

#### Words of Caution

You are in for a long read, as Vaio laptops have tons of problems with ACPI and similar functionality within Linux.  Not saying it's impossible, but you will surely learn a lot by the time you find your solution.